# Controller/View don't recognize a new model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have my asp.net MVC project with some models generated from the DB.

[image: Models]

Now I want to add some new models "manually" (without being generated from the DB) called "TrainingViewModels" to be used on the views.

The problem is that the models inside TrainingViewModels file are not recognized in any controller/view. Below the content of TrainingViewModels.cs:

```
    namespace FMS.Models
    {
        public class TrainingAdminViewModel
        {
            public Training Training { get; set; }
            public List<UserTrainings> UserTrainingsList { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

[image: Error]

If I paste the code above on AccountViewModels.cs file everything work as expected. I don't understand why I can't have it declared on a diferent file.

P.S. - It is not a missing import problem I think

Comment: *"It is not a missing import problem I think"* - There's a vast difference between what you think and what you've validated.  When you paste the model into the `AccountViewModels.cs` file, what is the containing namespace?  The model you show is in the `FMS.Models` namespace, does your controller have a `using` directive at the top of the file for that namespace?

Comment: @David Thanks for your message. The containing namespace in AccountViewModels.cs is the same, so FMS.Models. Given that on my controller I have a "using FMS.Models" at the top.

Comment: With that information I'm unable to replicate the behavior.  In the displayed error, what happens when you "Show potential fixes"?  Does Visual Studio suggest a namespace?

Comment: @David Thanks for your help. On "Show potential fixes" I can see "Generate class TrainingAdminViewModel in new file" , "Generate class TrainingAdminViewModel", "Generate nested class TrainingAdminViewModel" and "Generate new type". This is very strange. Do I have other option do define a new model in addition to the ones generated from the DB?

Comment: It sounds like something else entirely is going on here.  Something I find rather suspect is the screenshot of the `Models` folder.  Notice that there are expanders to the left of all of the files (likely for expanding to show the classes/definitions they contain), *except* for the file in question.  I'd start by deleting that file, doing a full clean and re-build of the application, potentially even re-starting Visual Studio between each step, and then re-adding a `.cs` class in the root of the project.  Once the class is working, you can move the location/namespace all you like.

Comment: @David Thanks. Followed that process and the issue was solved. Thanks!